# Label that wraps an input - how to make focus style visible only when focused using the keyboard, not mouse click?

Tags: html, css, focus

In the following example, the button's focus style is visible only when the button is focused using a keyboard (not mouse click).

How could I achieve the same effect on a label that wraps a hidden input?

In the code below, the label's focus style is visible when the label is focused using a keyboard or using a mouse click. I'd like it to be visible **only when focused using a keyboard.**

```css
.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  border: 0;
  width: 1;
  height: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
}

body {
  margin: 40px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 4px solid red;
}

button:focus-visible {
  outline: 4px solid red;
}

label:focus-within {
  outline: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Submit</button>
  <label>
    <input class="visually-hidden" type="checkbox" />
    Label
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the styles of the input inside it so it can style get the focus while being visually hidden:

```css
label {
  position:relative;
}
.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


button:focus-visible,
input:focus-visible{
  outline: 4px solid red;
}


body {
  margin: 40px;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Submit</button>
  <label>
    <input class="visually-hidden" type="checkbox" />
    Label
  </label>
</div>
```